# Photo viewer for Mac that can rotate (and save) pics while browsing folders

Tags: finder, photos.app, photos, preview

I am coming from Win and I am so disappointed by Mac's usability so far. My current problem is with maintaining photos. I usually take lot of pictures with my DSLR and I want a very simple solution to:

- browse through pictures where they are - without the need to copy them to some library like in iPhoto
- ability to easily rotate one or more of them at a time - unlike in preview where you can rotate only one picture in only one direction
- they should stay rotated(!!!) after I close the program - unlike x mac apps that I tried that do not save the rotation, which is totally useless
- large/full screen preview, with easy way to jump to prev/next photo without any headache inducing animation
- I want to know the number of pictures in a folder without going to a special menu like in Finder
- I don't want to spend more than $1-$2 on this simple app.

I am sorry if this sounds like a rant but I have tried so many options so far including spending money on useless app in the app store.

Comment: Have you tried Image Capture?

Comment: nope, let me google it

Answer (score 1):

So if you only want to spend $2 for such an app, you definitely will be disappointed in every direction you will take a look at.

Regarding my most famous and favourite graphics manipulation and imaging software "Graphicconverter", which can do everything you want and described, you would pay 35€. But if you want to, you can try it out.

http://www.lemkesoft.de/en/products/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is an excellent program that will do exactly what you are wanting, and it is free. It is called Phoenix Slides. It has been around for many years and I use it for exactly the same things you are wanting it for.

https://blyt.net/phxslides/ (that isn't a shortened link; it is the real URL to the developer's site)

You can rotate in either direction by using Shift-Cmd-L for Left and Shift-Cmd-R for Right.

Total image count will be to the left between the top browser section and the bottom thumbnail section.

Note that you can also show the total file count for a folder in Finder itself by going to View -> Show Status Bar. I also suggest enabling the Path Bar as well as I find it really useful. Both options will be at the bottom of the Finder window once enabled.